# Applying IAM roles to ECS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

Is there a way to run ECS containers under certain IAM roles?

Basically if you have a code / server that depends on IAM roles to access AWS resources (like S3 buckets or Dynamo tables), when you run that code / server as a ECS container, what will happen? can you control the roles per container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2**: Roles are now supported on the task level

**Update**: Lyft has an open source thing called 'metadataproxy' which claims to solve this problem, but its been received with some security issues.

When you launch a container host (the instance that connects to your cluster) this is called the container instance.

This instance will have an IAM role attached to it(in the guides it is ecsInstanceProfile I think is the name).

This instance runs the ecs agent (and subsequently docker). The way this works is when tasks are run, the actual containers make calls to/from AWS services, etc. This is swallowed up my the host (agent) since it is actually controlling the network in/out of the docker containers. This traffic in actuality now is coming from the agent.

So no, you cannot control on a per container basis the IAM role, you would need to do that via the instances (agents) that join the cluster.

Ie.

you join i-aaaaaaa and it has the ECS IAM policy + S3 read only to cluster.
you join i-bbbbbbb and it has the ECS IAM policy + S3 read/write to cluster.

You launch a task 'c' that needs r/w to S3. You'd want to make sure it runs on i-bbbbbb

Comment: This decribes what Marc meant https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html